# How to install Perl in personal unix area?

Tags: linux, installation, centos, perl

I'm working in a lab running a CentOS server with Perl 5.8.8.

I would like to install a newer version of Perl for my personal use only (i.e. do not affect other users). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::perlbrew) can do this; indeed it is a common method for intalling *many* local Perl installations, e.g. for compability testing.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting an error when trying to install a perl version using perlbrew: perlbrew install perl-5.10.1
Attempting to load conf from /home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/Conf.pm
Fail to get http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.10.1 (error: ) at /home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew line 1277.

Comment: @David: do you have a firewall or proxy in the way? That sounds like a download issue.

Comment: I have a proxy, but it is set in `env`. I have no problems downloading using `wget`, `git` and `cpan`. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: solved when removing the `http://` from the proxy...

Answer (score 4):

consulting the `README`of the perl distribution gives you:

```
INSTALLATION
============

If you're using a relatively modern operating system and want to
install this version of Perl locally, run the following commands:

   ./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl
   make test
   make install
```

which should be exactly what you are after.